# How should I clean up files and directories created by `git update-ref`?

Tags: git

If I use `git update-ref` to create a ref, in some cases `git update-ref -d` does not seem to let me clean up after it.

### Example #1

`git update-ref -d` does not let me delete refs outside of `.git/refs/`:

```sh
$ git update-ref foo HEAD
$ cat .git/foo
2245ac4343404174f5063821925a7d49747df622
$ git update-ref -d foo
error: refusing to update ref with bad name 'foo'
```

### Example #2

`git update-ref -d` does not remove a now-empty `refs/subdirectory`:

```sh
$ git update-ref refs/foo/bar/baz HEAD
$ git update-ref -d refs/foo/bar/baz
$ ls -a .git/refs/foo
./      ../
```

Do I need to remove `.git/foo` and `.git/refs/foo` manually (e.g. with `rm` and `rmdir`, respectively)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except for special refs, such as `HEAD`, all refs should start with `refs/`, and therefore you should always specify a fully qualified reference name to `git update-ref`.  This is a plumbing command and therefore it assumes you know how to use it properly.

In this particular case, you can delete the bad ref you created with `rm`, but in general you should avoid creating such refs in the first place.

As for the extra directory, it is harmless, and need not be cleaned up.  You can ignore it.

Note that not all refs are stored in individual files and so you should prefer to use `git update-ref` or a similar Git command.  Upstream is considering adding support for the reftable format and so it may not be the case that refs exist in individual files at all in some repositories.

Comment: It seems inconsistent to me that `git update-ref` assumes that I know what I'm doing if I do `git update-ref foo` but not when I do `git update-ref -d foo`. =/

Comment: It will also fail to let you update it in some cases.  In general, deleting or overwriting files directly under the `.git` directory is much riskier because you can obliterate important things like `.git/config`.  Creating useless files is silly, but won't break things.